# how to generate random number and assign it to label

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to generate a random number from 1-50, and then assign the number to certain label

I have already tried something like this

```
let randomNumber = arc4random()

numberLabel.text = randomNumber
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a number to a text field. You can do as follow:

```
let randomNumber = (arc4random() % 50) + 1
numberLabel.text = "\(randomNumber)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of `arc4random()` since it avoids [modulo bias](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx)

so use this instead.

```
numberLabel.text = "\(arc4random_uniform(50) + 1)"
```